# Displaying Images in CruiseControl.NET dashboard

Tags: image, cruisecontrol.net, dashboard, ndepend

I am trying to display the results of running NDepend on CruiseControl.NET. This includes images such as VisualNDepend , Abstractness vs Instability etc. I am however not able to display these results on the CruiseControl.NET dashboard. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Have you looked at this resource?  http://geekswithblogs.net/robz/archive/2009/06/02/ndepend-and-cruisecontrol.net.aspx

Comment: Great! Maybe you could answer your own question by explaining what you did that worked for you.